# Boost a record by point assigned to that record in Elastic Search

Tags: boost, elasticsearch

my question is how can we give dynamic boost value for every search record ?

In my case every record in the database have a point value assigned to it,and i have to assign that point as boost value on its search.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Please update your question here by clicking 'edit'... Please do not use the comment boxes.

Comment: You will probably also get some better answers if you tag the question with `tire` and or `rails` since it appears that's what you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using the following:

```
custom_score :script => "_score+doc['increase_relevance_points'].value" do
  boolean do
    should { match :increase_relevance_text, term}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index the point value from the database record into ElasticSearch as an integer. Once it's there you have lots of options using `custom_score` or [script based sorting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/).

If you want to boost each result by a factor of the `point_value` then the query might look something like:

```
"query": {
    "custom_score" : {
        "query" : {
            ....
        },
        "script" : "doc['point_value'].value * _score"
    }
}
```

Check out the [custom score query docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/) for full info.

Comment: i tried this but this doesn't suits my requirement

  mapping do
      indexes :attr1
      indexes :attr2
      indexes :increase_relevance_text
      indexes :decrease_relevance_text
  end

i have to increase boost of that record if the search term matches text in increase_relevance_text and for decrease vice versa.

Comment: i urgently need some solution.Please help me out.

Comment: I was trying this solution

custom_score do 
   query do 
      should { match :increase_relevance_text, term} 
   end 
   script '_score+ doc.increase_relevance_points' 
end
Getting error
undefined method `query' for #<Tire::Search::BooleanQuery:0xb3c845d4>

Please jamesc help me out.

Comment: Hi user, it would be helpful if you could update your question with the mappings and queries you've tried so far - that should help you get better responses from the community.

Comment: settings :analysis => {
:analyzer => {
 :my_analyzer => {
  "tokenizer"=>"lowercase",
    "filter"=> ["synonym", "porterStem"]
     }
   },            
   :filter => {    
      :synonym => {
         "type" => "synonym",
          "synonyms_path" => "#{Synonym.path}"
          }            
       }
  } do
  mapping do
   indexes :long_description, boost: 1,analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
   indexes :increase_relevance_points, type: :integer
   indexes :increase_relevance_text
   indexes :prices do
    indexes :supplier_active, type: 'boolean'
   indexes :state, type: :integer
  end
 end
end

Comment: tire.search(page: page, per_page: per_page) do     
 query do
 boolean(:minimum_number_should_match => 1) do
  if term.present?
   should { match :long_description, term}#, :operator => "and"}#, :type => :phrase }
   should do
    custom_score :boost => 1.0, :script => "_score+doc['increase_relevance_points'].value" do
     boolean do
     should { match :increase_relevance_text, term}             
     end
    end
   end 
   end
 end
 end
  filter :not, :exists => {:field => :deleted_at}
  sort { by order_field, order_direction } if options[:sort].present?
end

Comment: the above written custom_score is running not throwing any error,but not increase boost value.